# Parsing HTML with Lxml

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I need help parsing out some text from a page with lxml.  I tried beautifulsoup and the html of the page I am parsing is so broken, it wouldn't work.  So I have moved on to lxml, but the docs are a little confusing and I was hoping someone here could help me.

[Here](http://www.keelshield.com/store_locator.html?&cHash=8e1b56e557&tx_spdirectory_pi1[mode]=detail&tx_spdirectory_pi1[modifier]=cat&tx_spdirectory_pi1[value]=189) is the page I am trying to parse, I need to get the text under the "Additional Info" section.  Note, that I have a lot of pages on this site like this to parse and each pages html is not always exactly the same (might contain some extra empty "td" tags).  Any suggestions as to how to get at that text would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: According to firebug the xpath is:

 `/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]`.  

You'd probably start at `//*[@id="BelowTheFold"]`. I think the tbodies should be removed.

Is the text "additional info" always there?

Comment: Hmmm,  I am not really familiar with xpath.  Yes, the additional info is text is always there.  One thing I know is that things like: td[3] won't work because the html isn't exactly consistent on each page.  So one page it might be td[3] and the next might be td[4].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2

def text_tail(node):
    yield node.text
    yield node.tail

url='http://bit.ly/bf1T12'
doc=lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
for elt in doc.iter('td'):
    text=elt.text_content()
    if text.startswith('Additional  Info'):
        blurb=[text for node in elt.itersiblings('td')
               for subnode in node.iter()
               for text in text_tail(subnode) if text and text!=u'\xa0']
        break
print('\n'.join(blurb))
```

yields

> For over 65 years, Carl Stirn's Marine
>   has been setting new standards of
>   excellence and service for boating
>   enjoyment.  Because we offer quality
>   merchandise, caring, conscientious,
>   sales and service, we have been able
>   to make our customers our good
>   friends.
>
> Our 26,000 sq. ft. facility includes a
>   complete parts and accessories
>   department, full service department
>   (Merc. Premier dealer with 2 full time
>   Mercruiser Master Tech's), and new,
>   used, and brokerage sales.

**Edit:**  Here is an alternate solution based on Steven D. Majewski's xpath which addresses the OP's comment that the number of tags separating 'Additional  Info' from the blurb can be unknown:

```
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2

url='http://bit.ly/bf1T12'
doc=lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))

blurb=doc.xpath('//td[child::*[text()="Additional  Info"]]/following-sibling::td/text()')

blurb=[text for text in blurb if text != u'\xa0']
print('\n'.join(blurb))
```

Comment: You could also use:
doc.xpath( '(//td[descendant-or-self::*[text()="Additional  Info"]])[last()]/following-sibling::td[2]/text()' )
instead of iterating. ( That xpath may be more complicated than necessary -- I'm trying to avoid depending on the <strong> or other tags, the same as your iterating code. )

Comment: The only problem with this I could see is the getnext().getnext(), because the html might not always be exactly the same on each page.  One page might only have one td tag in between the text, the next page might have two td tags.  Is there anyway to iter over the tr tags until you find the one with the additional info text, then strip out the html and you would be left with just the text ... only a thougt.

Comment: @Steven: Thank you for the XPath. I'm still trying to learn XPath, and your example is very instructive for me.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that.  xpath is pretty interesting stuff. Appropriate the help from both of you.

Comment: @benEliott it isn't spam. If you're going to remove output samples (why???), at least do it properly. Reverting.

Comment: Dead link. url='http://bit.ly/bf1T12' yields:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..." Line 9, in <module>
    doc=lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
...
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden